# How to make length difference between two network analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I have one quite challenging problem and can't find solution for it.

I am doing closest facility analysis via network analysis. I have bus stations as facilities and houses as incidents. I have run analysis for this scenario and saved it. Then I did the same again but I included also flood as polygon barrier into analysis. Now I want to find out which incidents (houses) have longer distance when there is flooding compare to scenario when there is no flooding. Note, that during this analysis there were some houses which were excluded as errors as they are sooo flooded that they can't access road.

I was thinking to export both tables in Excel and simply minus them from each other and then import them back to include difference. Problem is that numbers of "Shape_Length" are not in same row so in the end there are less rows for scenario with flooding. Nevertheless ID of incidents is matching for both scenarios so I can find difference for each house manually. Problem is that I have approx. 9 000 of these houses... so I need to find for some smarter solution.

Do you know please about some good solution how to make difference between these two scenarios so I could see what difference of length is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can simply [Join](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) both output layers based on incident IDs and calculate length differences using Field Calculator.